# Refresh photo gallery in swift

Tags: ios, swift, gallery

I've made a photo gallery and now I want to know how to refresh it. If I open my app and have 5 photos in my library I see all of them. If I press on the home button and take another photo and open the app again I can't see that. So I have to close the app manually and restart to make it work

Comment: not getting your question,You are using UIImagePicker to pick photos from Device ?

Comment: You have to call fetch images function  in viewDidAppear instead of ViewDidLoad